# Take the content of a single tag from an xml file with the requests module

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I make a request with python requests module to a soap service with this code:

```
response = requests.get(url,data=body,headers=headers)
```

and the service return this xml as response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aa="example.com/api"><soap:Body>
            <aa:GetStockFileResponse> GetStockFileResponseType
                <aa:TestMode> boolean </aa:TestMode>
                <aa:Errors> ArrayOfError
                    <aa:Error> Error
                        <aa:Code> int </aa:Code>
                        <aa:Description> string </aa:Description>
                    </aa:Error>
                </aa:Errors>
                <aa:Warnings> ArrayOfWarning
                    <aa:Warning> Warning
                        <aa:Code> int </aa:Code>
                        <aa:Description> string </aa:Description>
                    </aa:Warning>
                </aa:Warnings>
                <aa:StockFileFormat> StockFileFormat (string) </aa:StockFileFormat>
                <aa:FieldDelimiter> StringLength1 (string) </aa:FieldDelimiter>
                <aa:File> base64Binary </aa:File>
            </aa:GetStockFileResponse>
        </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I need to write to a csv file the content of `<aa:File> base64Binary </aa:File>`that is a base64 encoded csv file.
My code to write the response is:

```
with open ('test.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write (response.content)
```

that obviously write the whole xml...
How to take only the `<aa:File> base64Binary </aa:File>` content?

Comment: This is a xml parsing problem and has nothing to do with python-requests. Any xml parser will solve your problem, so pick one and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the solution?

```
import re

xmlText = '<foo>Foo</foo><aa:File> base64Binary </aa:File><bar>Bar</bar>'

# Target to extract: " base64Binary "

content = re.findall(r'<aa:File>(.+?)</aa:File>', xmlText)

print(content)  # outputs " base64Binary "
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I think is better to use a parser like @bruno desthuilliers said. I'm trying to resolve with xml.etree.ElementTree, any suggestions appreciated